# What is the definition of distributive lower semi lattice?

Tags: logic, order-theory

What is the definition of distributive lower semi lattice? 
is showing that a $poset$ is closed under finite disjunctions enought to show that is a distributive lower semi lattice?
also I don't know when elements are formulas, disjunction means logical disjunction?

Comment: If you had asked a question about distributive lower semilattices, I'd probably asked what is that. I know what are [Distributive semilattices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semilattice#Distributive_semilattices), but distributive lower semilattices, I've never heard about. I think that's is a clarification that you should do, but if that's exactly the content of your question, I don't think this question makes any sense. (But perhaps I'm wrong, judging by the upvotes...)

Comment: Search for distributive meet semi lattices

Comment: "Chot" and "clodes" are not words.

Comment: sorry,thanks,edited.